# Use array_construct in filter

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sql-query like this:

```
select
    field_name,
    field_value
from 
    my_table
where field_name not in (array_construct('A', 'B'))
```

The array_construct is something I get out of another column.
I want to use it as a filter with an in-condition.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

I get an error message like: Can not convert parameter 'ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('A', 'B')' of type [ARRAY] into expected type [VARCHAR(120)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html) function:

```
select
    field_name,
    field_value
from 
    my_table
where NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(filed_name::VARIANT, array_construct('A', 'B'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A more compact form using `[]`

```
where not array_contains( [col1], [col2,col3] )
```